# Exclude 0's from arrayformula

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-query-language

```
=ArrayFormula({"Test"; query(value(CTA!C2:C)*0.8)})
```

How would I exclude the rest of the 0's in empty cells?

[image]

Comment: Try something like `=INDEX({"Test";FILTER(CTA!C2:C,ISNUMBER(1/CTA!C2:C))*0,8})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({"Test"; IFERROR(1/(1/(VALUE(CTA!C2:C)*0.8)))})
```

or:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({"Test"; QUERY(VALUE(CTA!C2:C)*0.8; "where Col1 <> 0"; )})
```

Comment: They both worked. Is one more efficient then the other?

Comment: @cpaone first hides it and the second one removes it

Comment: @player0 You actually had a break. ^_^

Comment: Yes haha. Thanks for the help like always!

Answer (score 1):

Use INDEX+COUNTA to constrain the input:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({Test;CTA!C2:INDEX(CTA!C:C,COUNTA(CTA!C:C))*0.8})
```